# How can i refresh 'if condition' on widget tree in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, widget

```
class CustomDateAndTime extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomDateAndTime({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomDateAndTimeState createState() => _CustomDateAndTimeState();
}

class _CustomDateAndTimeState extends State<CustomDateAndTime> {
  bool checkDate = false;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  String dateText = '';
  late DateTime date;
  var formatter = new DateFormat('d MMM, yyyy');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 4,
              child: datePicker(context),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: Icon(Icons.date_range_outlined),
              ),
            ),
            if (checkDate == true)
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        controller.clear();
                        checkDate = false;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField datePicker(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      readOnly: true,
      controller: controller,
      onTap: () async {
        date = (await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: DateTime(2021, 8),
          lastDate: DateTime(2050),
        ))!;
        if (date.day == DateTime.now().day) {
          controller.text = "TODAY";
          checkDate = true;
        } else if (date.day == DateTime.now().day + 1) {
          controller.text = "TOMORROW";
          checkDate = true;
        } else {
          controller.text = formatter.format(date);
          checkDate = true;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In this code, If a date is entered, I will add a delete button, but to do this, the if block needs to work again. But it's not working. Although it is 'statefull widget', it does not go inside the if block.
Summary; A new button will be added when the date is entered. How can I do that ? .... ....................................................................................................................

Comment: else {
          controller.text = formatter.format(date);
        setState((){  checkDate = true;})
        }

Comment: try to wrap the reassignment with setState to rebuild the widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason why **if block** didn't called because it's only called first time when widget build so when you change it's value later won't call again.

there are many solutions the simplest one every time you want change **checkDate** variable put the statement in setState() like that

```
setState(() =>  checkDate = false);
```

to ensure that widget create again so the code enter **if block**

or use ValueListenableBuilder it's more efficient

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-ZG-jS5QHQ

Comment: Thank you Hossam. I got it done with 'ValueListenableBuilder'.

Comment: @Mucahit You're Welcome, great job

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a setState once date is selected. For instance

```
    Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
  }
```

Comment: thanks man, i solved my problem with 'ValueListenableBuilder'.

Answer (score 0):

Stateful Widgets rebuilds, repaints screen when `setState()` method is triggered. So, when a state variable like "checkDate" is changed by any code block, you should also trigger setState() method.

Best practice is wrapping your re-assign line with setState method:

```
if (date.day == DateTime.now().day) {
          controller.text = "TODAY";
          setState((){ checkDate = true;});
        } else if (date.day == DateTime.now().day + 1) {
          controller.text = "TOMORROW";
          setState((){ checkDate = true;});
        } else {
          controller.text = formatter.format(date);
          setState((){ checkDate = true;});
        }
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand how to wrap the if block with setState in that case. But I solved my problem with ValueListenableBuilder. But thank you for your time.